# Finding the best-fit object from an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, loops, logic

Given an array in the following structure (although obviously with many more items in it):

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [currency] => 1
            [role] => 3
            [client_company] => 
            [client_group] => 
            [hourly_rate] => 115.00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [currency] => 1
            [role] => 1
            [client_company] => 
            [client_group] => 
            [hourly_rate] => 115.00
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [currency] => 1
            [role] => 3
            [client_company] => 58
            [client_group] => 
            [hourly_rate] => 110.00
        )
)
```

I'm trying to create a function that will take four parameters:

- $role
- $currency
- $company [optional]
- $group [optional]

("groups" are children of "companies": if a group is specified, a parent company will always also be specified)

...and that will return the "hourly rate" value from the item that best fits those parameters, on the basis that:

if $row, $currency, $company and $group are specified:

- find a rate that matches the role, currency, company and group.
- if there isn't one, find one that matches the role, currency and company
- if there isn't one, find one that matches the role and currency
- if there isn't one, return FALSE

if just $row, $currency and $company are specified:

- find a rate that matches the role, currency and company
- if there isn't one, find one that matches the role and currency
- if there isn't one, return FALSE

if just $row and $currency are specified:

- find a rate that matches the role and currency
- if there isn't one, return FALSE

What I've got is below, and it works. However, it's ugly as sin. There must be a more elegant way than just bashing a load of if/else and loops together. However, it's Friday and I've had too much pizza for lunch and my brain has become ensludged with cheese.

Can you help?

```
$hourly_rate = FALSE;

if ( !empty($group) && !empty($company) ) {

    foreach ( $rates_cache as $rate ) {

        if ( $rate->currency == $currency && $rate->role == $role && (int) $rate->client_company === (int) $company && (int) $rate->client_group === (int) $group ) {
            $hourly_rate = $rate->hourly_rate;
        }

    }

    if ( empty($hourly_rate) ) {

        foreach ( $rates_cache as $rate ) {

            if ( $rate->currency == $currency && $rate->role == $role && (int) $rate->client_company === (int) $company ) {
                $hourly_rate = $rate->hourly_rate;
            }

        }
    }

    if ( empty($hourly_rate) ) {

        foreach ( $rates_cache as $rate ) {

            if ( $rate->currency == $currency && $rate->role == $role ) {
                $hourly_rate = $rate->hourly_rate;
            }

        }
    }

}else if ( !empty($company) ) {

    foreach ( $rates_cache as $rate ) {

        if ( $rate->currency == $currency && $rate->role == $role && (int) $rate->client_company === (int) $company ) {
            $hourly_rate = $rate->hourly_rate;
        }

    }

    if ( empty($hourly_rate) ) {

        foreach ( $rates_cache as $rate ) {

            if ( $rate->currency == $currency && $rate->role == $role ) {
                $hourly_rate = $rate->hourly_rate;
            }

        }
    }

}else{

    foreach ( $rates_cache as $rate ) {

        if ( $rate->currency == $currency && $rate->role == $role ) {
            $hourly_rate = $rate->hourly_rate;
        }

    }

}

return $hourly_rate;
```

Comment: Honestly, I think this is great code -- it's clear and it implements the specification precisely, and if the need ever arises to change it, it'll be very easy to do. The only thing I'd change is I'd add your succinct description of the choices to the code as comments.

Comment: If that is all the logic that will go into those ... it works, but if it is more complex, and that is just an example you should look into these three patterns.  Factory, Strategy, and Chain of Responsibility.

Comment: That's the whole logic, nothing more. But it's not DRY. It loops through the same array up to three times. And it looks like a simpleton wrote it. Which, to be fair, I did.

Answer (score 1):

### Assumption

I believe your `cache` is always in the format below

**Cache Format:**

```
$cache = array(
        0 => (object) (array(
                'currency' => 1,
                'role' => 3,
                'client_company' => '',
                'client_group' => '',
                'hourly_rate' => '115.00'
        )),
        1 => (object) (array(
                'currency' => 1,
                'role' => 1,
                'client_company' => '',
                'client_group' => '',
                'hourly_rate' => '115.00'
        )),
        2 => (object) (array(
                'currency' => 1,
                'role' => 3,
                'client_company' => 58,
                'client_group' => '',
                'hourly_rate' => '110.00'
        ))
);
```

### Your Revised Function

```
$param = array(
        "role" => 1,
        "currency" => 1
);

echo find($cache, $param)->hourly_rate;
```

**Function Used**

```
function find($cache, $param) {
    $mx = array();
    if (! isset($param['role']) || ! isset($param['currency']))
        throw new Exception("Missing Role Or Currency");
    foreach ( $cache as $k => $r ) {
        foreach ( array_keys(array_intersect($param, (array) $r)) as $key ) {
            if ($r->{$key} == $param[$key]) {
                isset($mx[$k]) ? $mx[$k] ++ : $mx[$k] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    arsort($mx);
    return $cache[key($mx)];
}
```

### More Complex: Another Approach

**Usage**

```
$param = array(
        "role" => 1,
        "currency" => 1
);

$process = new Process($cache);
echo $process->find($param)->best()->hourly_rate; // Outputs 115.00
```

**Multiple Results**

When find best fit .. there is possibility you would get more than one result

```
$param = array(
        "role" => 3,
        "currency" => 1
);

$process = new Process($cache);
var_dump($process->find($param)->results());
```

**Output**

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'currency' => int 1
      public 'role' => int 3
      public 'client_company' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'client_group' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'hourly_rate' => string '115.00' (length=6)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'currency' => int 1
      public 'role' => int 3
      public 'client_company' => int 58
      public 'client_group' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'hourly_rate' => string '110.00' (length=6)
```

**Not getting best result**

You can see based on your parameters you are getting 2  if you are looking for cheapest prize and you call

```
$param = array(
        "role" => 3,
        "currency" => 1
);

echo Process::quick($cache, $param)->best()->hourly_rate; // returns 115.00 but that is not the cheapest
```

**Resolution**

The solution is you can add filter and  `sort`

```
$param = array(
        "role" => 3,
        "currency" => 1
);

$sort = function ($a, $b) {
    return $a->hourly_rate < $b->hourly_rate ? - 1 : 1;
};

echo Process::quick($cache, $param)->sort($sort)->best()->hourly_rate; // 110
```

**Getting all Related**

You can also just loop through all the result and select the columns you want insted of just getting best result

```
foreach ( Process::quick($cache, $param)->sort($sort)->getColoum("client_company", "hourly_rate") as $result ) {
    print_r($result);
}
```

**Output**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [client_company] => 58
    [hourly_rate] => 110.00
)
stdClass Object
(
    [client_company] => 
    [hourly_rate] => 115.00
)
```

**Updated Class**

To add all this additional functions you need to upgrade your class to

```
    class Process implements JsonSerializable, IteratorAggregate {
    private $cache;
    private $matrix = array();
    private $final = array();

    function __construct($cache) {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }

    function find($param) {
        if (! isset($param['role']) || ! isset($param['currency']))
            throw new Exception("Missing Role Or Currency");
        foreach ( $this->cache as $k => $rate ) {
            $keys = array_intersect($param, (array) $rate);
            foreach ( array_keys($keys) as $key ) {
                if ($rate->{$key} == $param[$key]) {
                    isset($this->matrix[$k]) ? $this->matrix[$k] ++ : $this->matrix[$k] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        arsort($this->matrix);
        $this->matrix = array_keys(array_filter($this->matrix, function ($v) {
            return $v >= 2;
        }));
        $this->final = $this->sortArray($this->cache, $this->matrix);
        return $this;
    }

    public static function quick($cache, $param) {
        $process = new Process($cache);
        return $process->find($param);
    }

    public function best() {
        reset($this->final);
        return empty($this->final) ?  : current($this->final);
    }

    public function results() {
        return $this->final;
    }

    public function limit($length = 0) {
        $this->final = array_slice($this->final, 0, $length);
        return $this;
    }

    public function sort(Callable $function) {
        usort($this->final, $function);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getColoum() {
        $arg = array_flip(func_get_args());
        foreach ( $this->final as &$s ) {
            foreach ( $s as $k => $v ) {
                if (! isset($arg[$k]))
                    unset($s->{$k});
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function getIterator() {
        return new ArrayIterator($this->final);
    }

    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return json_encode($this->final);
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->jsonSerialize();
    }

    private function sortArray(array $array, array $orderArray) {
        $ordered = array();
        foreach ( $orderArray as $key => $value ) {
            array_key_exists($value, $array) and $ordered[$value] = $array[$value];
        }
        return $ordered;
    }
}
```